# Overriding firmware installion recipe in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am trying to reduce the amount of firmware that is included in a Yocto image to reduce its size. for example I have these i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin and i915/bxt_guc_ver9_29.bin, which are not needed.

My Yocto project build platform has this recipe linux-firmware_git.bb at meta/recipes-kernel/linux-firmware. Obviously I can edit this file to exclude items of firmware. But because it is one of the base files of the distribution I'm using I want to leave it intact.

I have tried creating a linux-firmware_git.bbappend file which contains the following entries:

```
LICENSE_${PN}-i915       = ""
LICENSE_${PN}-i915-license = ""
FILES_${PN}-i915-license = ""
FILES_${PN}-i915-license = ""
FILES_${PN}-i915-license = ""
FILES_${PN}-i915         = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-i915      = ""
```

Unfortunately this bbappend prevents all firmware being installed in the image rather than just excluding the *-i915 files.

Could someone please tell my how to override the linux-firmware recipe so that unneeded files are excluded.

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Comment: You need to remove files in `do_install()` of your bbappend.

Comment: In the firmware recipe, there is no reference to any files in the  'do_install()' function. I'm not sure how or where the i915 files get referenced and pulled in.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Look at `FILES_${PN}-***`.

Answer (score 2):

After much digging around, I found it was quite easy to achieve what I wanted.

To remove particular items firmware, eg i915, I needed to do this:

```
FILES_${PN}_remove += "${nonarch_base_libdir}/firmware/LICENSE.i915 \
                       ${nonarch_base_libdir}/firmware/i915"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-i915      = "${PN}-i915-license"

do_install_append() {        
   rm -r ${D}/${nonarch_base_libdir}/firmware/i915
}
```

I hope this is helpful to others.